Is the property $S_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$ preserved when the metrizable separable topology is finer?
Let $(X,\tau)$ be a metrizable separable space and $X$ has the property $S_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$.
Suppose that $(X,\tau')$ be a metrizable separable space such that $\tau\subset \tau'$.
Will space $(X,\tau')$ then have the property $S_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$ ?

What is $S_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_principle

$\binom{\Omega}{\Gamma}=S_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$
